# Choice of Linux IPC technique

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I am building an application which takes as it's input an executable , executes it and keeps track of dynamic memory allocations among others to help track down memory errors.

After reading the name of the executable I create a child process,link the executable with my module ( which includes my version of malloc family of functions) and execute the executable provided by the user. The parent process will consist of a GUI ( using QT framework ) where I want to display warnings/errors/number of allocations.

I need to communicate the number of mallocs/frees and a series of warning messages to the parent process in real-time. After the users application has finished executing I wish to display the number of memory leaks. ( I have taken care of all the backend coding needed for this in the shared library I link against).

Real-Time:

I though of 2 different approaches to communicate this information.

1. Child process will write to 2 pipes ( 1 for writing whether allocation/free happened and another for writing a single integer to denote a warning message).
2. I though of simply sending a signal to denote whether an allocation has happened. Also create signals for each of the warning messages. I will map these to the actual warnings (strings) in the parent process.

Is the signal version as efficient as using a pipe? Is it feasible ? Is there any better choice , as I do care about efficiency:)

After user's application finishes executing:

I need to send the whole data structure I use to keep track of memory leaks here. This could possibly be very large so I am not sure which IPC method would be the most efficient.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Dare I ask, what are you doing this for? (just interested)

Comment: It's my undergraduate final year project, shall I mark this as homework ?

Comment: No I was just curious, if you mark it as homework you really only gain people giving you a wall of references instead of the help on a code snippet that your probably really looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a combination of shared memory and a socket.  Have a shared memory area, say 1MB, and log all your information in some standard format in that buffer.  If/when the buffer fills or the process terminates you send a message, via the socket, to the reader.  After the reader ACKs you can clear the buffer and carry on.

To answer caf's concern about target application corruption, just use the [mprotect](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/mprotect.html) system call to remove permissions (set `PROT_NONE`) from the shared memory area before giving control to your target process.  Naturally this means you'll have to set `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE` before updating your log on each allocation, not sure if this is a performance win with the `mprotect` calls thrown in.

EDIT: in case it isn't blindingly obvious, you can have multiple buffers (or one divided into N parts) so you can pass control back to the target process immediately and not wait for the reader to ACK.  Also, given enough computation resources the reader can run as often as it wants reading the currently active buffer and performing real-time updates to the user or whatever it's reading for.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a unix-domain socket, it's a little more flexible than a pipe, can be configured for datagram mode which save you having to find message boundaries, and makes it easy to move to a network interface later.

Answer (score 2):

Signals are definitely not the way to do this.  In general, signals are best avoided whenever possible.

A pipe solution is fine.  You could also use shared memory, but that would be more vulnerable to accidental corruption by the target application.